# Proof of Hilbert’s famous “Nullstellensatz” theorem:

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

The book proves the case for $a=(0,0,...,0)$ and says that the proof for the arbitrary point $a$ can be using the change of the variables $x_i=x_i’+a_i$. This should be trivial but I don’t get it (I get the rest of the proof except the change of variable part (although I haven’t even attempted the converse yet).

Edit:
$x_i=x_i’+a_i$ Means that $x_i’=-a_i$? Sorry the more I think about this problem the more confused I get.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't get? For instance, when you try to run the proof for an arbitrary point, what's the last statement that you understand and the first statement you don't?

Comment: I just don’t get why a change of variable is helpful for the arbitrary case. I don’t even get what $x_i’$ is representing. I think if someone gave the case for a particular $a$ and used change of variable to solve, I would understand.

Comment: Think about the ring $\mathbb{C}[x'_1,...,x'_n] \cong \mathbb{C}[x_1 - a_1,...,x_n - a_n]$. Is it isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$?

Comment: I think it’s isomorphic since they both have the same range and etc..

Comment: Is this right: when $x_i=a_i+x’_i$ and we set $x_i=a_i$ we get $x’_i=0$ So it looks as if $a_i=0$ and $f(0,0,...0)$ is what we are dealing with now. Right? Thank you, at least I know I was on the wrong path now (even if this logic is incorrect)

Answer (score 1):

From the proof we have the isomorphism
$$s_a : \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]/M_a \to \mathbb{C},\quad f(x) \to f(a) $$
You have the problem solved for $a=0$. So consider the isomorphism
$$\phi_{a} : \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n] \to \mathbb{C}[x'_1,...,x'_n] $$
and sends $f(x_1,...,x_n)  \mapsto \phi_a(f) = f(x'_1+a_1,...,x'_n+a_1)$. So if $f\in \mathbb{C}[x_1,...,x_n]$ with $f(a_1,...,a_n)= 0$, then $\phi_a(f)(0,...,0) = 0$ which implies $\phi_a(f) \in M_0 = (x'_1,...,x'_n)$. From this taking preimages we see that $ f\in (x_1-a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$.